# Horizontal UIStackView - how to align items inside so that one is floated left and the other sticks in center?

Tags: ios, xib, uistackview

I am making a "preferences" screen, and struggling with the layout aspect of the top header. I have a simple "back" button, and a label. The requirement is, the back button must always be floated left, and the label must be at the center, with its own content centered.

So far, I created a stackview (horizontal) containing both the items. I have specified distribution to equal spacing, and added width constraints as follows:
button - 60
label - 200

This looks good on one screen, but I am sure it is not gonna work because screen widths vary on different devices and also between portrait/landscape.

In CSS, this would have simply been specifying that the button be float:left and the label be margin:auto, how do I make this work in the XIB?

Here is a screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: Add a third, empty UIView to the stack view. Set its width to be equal to your back button. Don't set any other widths.  Set the label to have centered  text. Set the stack view distribution to `.fill`

Comment: You don't, without tricks like Paul describes.

Comment: Is that the only option @Paul?, I assumed there may be a mainstream way to do this, sorry really new to iOS.

Comment: There may be other ways but they would be similar approaches nothing "out of the box".

Comment: Your UI is really similar to that of a navigation controller/navigation bar. Any specific reason for not using them?

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri - Do you want your label to be centered ***in the empty space between the button and the right edge***? Or, do you want your label centered ***to the width of the view / screen***? If centered to the view, what do you want to happen if the label has too much text to fit?

Comment: @Losiowaty Actually my case is quite different, I've explored the possibility of using a UINavigationController and it wasn't feasible.

Comment: @DonMag It has to be centered to the width of the screen, if there is too much text it will be cropped (however, in my case there is a limit on the label text size anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options...

---

The simplest, and closest to your CSS description:

[image]

Button is constrained 0 from top, 8 from leading (adjust as desired); label is constrained centered vertically to button, centered horizontally to view.

The drawback: if label gets too much text, it will overlap the button.

---

Second option:

[image]

Same as above, but add a "spacer" `UIView` to upper right... constrain it 0 to top, 8 to trailing, centered vertically to button, and constrain it equal width and equal height to button. Then, add `>= 8` constraints to the label leading to button trailing, and label trailing to spacer view leading. That will allow the label to expand horizontally based on its text, but will prevent overlap (text will be `...` truncated if there is too much to fit).

---

Third option - using stack view:

[image]

Stack view settings:

```
Axis: Horizontal
Alignment: Fill
Distribution: Fill
Spacing: 8
```

Constrain the stack view 0 to top, 8 leading and trailing (just for a little padding on the sides), add a button, label and `UIView`. Constrain the 
"spacer" view equal width to the button. Set the Horizontal `Content Hugging Priority = 1000` for the button (will keep it the width of its title).

There are other approaches, partially depending on if you want to do anything else you haven't shown here, but all three of these will do the job.

Comment: @NRitH - ***I*** am not trying to. Your question should probably be a comment for the OP...

Comment: I am going to try all these out, although I achieved this with the spacer method, thanks a ton @DonMag. Can't be more pleased with the time you took to answer my question.